# How can I change the name associated with my Gmail Account?

Tags: gmail, google-account

If I go into Settings > Accounts and Import, under Send mail as I see the name associated with my account. I would like to change this. If I click Edit Info, I see that the name is selected and it says `your name in Google accounts`. So I would like to change my Google accounts name so that it automatically uses this one all the time.

I went into my Google Account settings and then pressed "Edit your personal info" and changed the name. When I refresh Gmail's page, nothing happens, it still shows the old name. I tried logging out and back in to Gmail, but it didn't help. When I send an email message, it still shows the old name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one of my accounts, the name was updated immediately after sending an email message. On another account, I just checked back after several minutes, and it showed the right name. So it seems that this is either a delayed process, or you must invoke some functionality (e.g. send an email) for Gmail to pull these settings from your account.

Comment: It's been this way for over two months now. Every time I've manually corrected Gmail, but it doesn't want to learn.